# Finding out if the same property occurs on multiple AD users

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm pretty new on Powershell and this is by far the trickiest task I have gotten so far. I want to write a script that shows me if the same personal identity number occurs on multiple AD users.

I have managed to get a list of all AD users and their ID numbers using the Powershell Active Directory module and the following:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=X,DC=X,DC=X,DC=X" -Properties PersonalIdentityNumber | Select-Object Name,PersonalIdentityNumber | Where-Object {$_.PersonalIdentityNumber} | Sort-Object -Property PersonalIdentityNumber
```

Although, I am not sure where to go from there. I suspect that I will have to use a for or foreach loop in some way, but I have tested a bit and not made any concluions. It will most likely be too heavy to compare every user against all other users, but I think that every user can be compared to the 20 users before or after, since matching ID numbers will probably be on users with the same name.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `Group-Object` cmdlet to group the users based on the value of the `PersonalIdentityNumber` property:

```
$usersWithPIN = Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=X,DC=X,DC=X,DC=X" -Properties PersonalIdentityNumber | Select-Object Name,PersonalIdentityNumber | Where-Object {$_.PersonalIdentityNumber}

$usersWithSamePINGroups = $usersWithPIN |Group-Object PersonalIdentityNumber |Where-Object Count -gt 1
```

`$usersWithSamePINGroups` will now contain zero or more `Group` objects with a `Count` property (the number of users sharing a given PIN), and a `Group` property containing the user objects in question